# Does Standard Type 2 Rules applies for lands? MTG

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does Standard Type 2 Cycling Rules applies for lands too? Those lands that generates two, three manas for example?

Comment: What do you mean by "Standard Type 2 Cycling Rules"?

Comment: All I can think is that "cycling" refers to sets rotating out of the format?

Comment: In that case, it might be a duplicate of http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/how-can-i-tell-which-sets-are-currently-legal-in-various-formats or http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/11546/are-basic-lands-mana-block-set-agnostic or maybe even http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/15363/can-you-play-older-versions-of-cards-in-standard. But probably the first one

Answer (score 4):

There's no rule that says nonbasic lands aren't affected by format restrictions, so yes. Lands can and do rotate out of standard.

Comment: Useful clarification if the question survives: Basic lands (Plains, Island, Swamp, Mountain, Forest) never rotate out.